# disable reloading page after submitting form

Tags: php, javascript, html

I Have a script which create dynamic table. After user click a button, next `row` at the bottom of the table is added.:

```
function createRow()
        {
            var options='<select name="nameselect'>
            options+='<option>one</option>';
            options+='</select>';
        options+='<input type=\'submit\' name=\'loadReq\' value=\'Pobierz dane\' />';
            var form = document.createElement('form'); // create row node
            var row = document.createElement('tr'); // create row node
            var col = document.createElement('td'); // create column node
            var col2 = document.createElement('td'); // create second column node
            var col3 = document.createElement('td'); // create column node
            var col4 = document.createElement('td'); // create second column node
            var col5 = document.createElement('td'); // create column node
            var col6 = document.createElement('td');
            form.appendChild(col);
            row.appendChild(form); // append first column to row
            row.appendChild(col2); // append second column to row
            row.appendChild(col3); // append first column to row
            row.appendChild(col4); // append second column to row
            row.appendChild(col5); // append first column to row
            //row.appendChild(col6);
            col.innerHTML = options; 

            col2.innerHTML = 'some text'; // put data in second column
            col3.innerHTML = 'some text';
            col4.innerHTML = 'some text';           
            col5.innerHTML = 'some text';
            table.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', row);
            counter++;
        }
```

So right now im adding the row with `some text` value in 2-5 columns and with `drop down list` with button as a form in the first column.

But whenever I submit my form, page is reloading, so efect of my `JavaScript` function is no longer there, in the result i get exacly same page as i opened before and row I added disappear. 
 Is it possible to submit form and don't loose efect of `JavaScript` Function?

Comment: At the end of your function add `return false;`

Comment: Unfortunately no success...

Comment: Do you really want to submit the form (in this case to another page) or just click on a button that execute Javascript ?

Comment: If you really need to do a submit, you'll need to remember the entire current contents of the page between loads. Otherwise, an AJAX call may suffice.

Comment: Kind of I do after submitting form I am able to "read" the value of `select` tag inside of my php in order to put value in other column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are kind of lost with all the possibilities of PHP/Javascript.

To update what you are displaying to a user, you don't need to submit the form even if you want to use data entered in the form by the user. It could be done using Javascript (without reloading the page) :

```
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
```

Now if you want to submit the form to get and use user input in your PHP (to update a database for example...) you can submit the form and when you re-display it (after page reload), initialize it with the previous user input. Doing something like that :

```
echo '<input type="text" name="userInput" value="'.$_POST['userInput'].'">';
```

Comment: positive. You are entirely right. But you have to see on my problem as a one part - Problem is that on submitting the form `var col = document.createElement('td');` those elements disappears and so is inserted row and i have no idea how to avoid this..

Comment: What I tried to tell you is that because you don't have a global view of the process of submitting, generating the page, etc., you don't search in the right direction.

Comment: You can either process the user input in PHP and construct your table in accordance (with the right number of rows and the right data in it) or don't submit the form and process all the data using Javascript...

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using AJAX to submit the form: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/

This way, you can use the data in the form to perform some actions, and provide feedback to the user without having to trigger a full page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Either cancel the default behaviour of the button click, or change this from an `<input type="submit">` to an `<input type="button">` or `<button>` (both have no default behaviour).

Comment: I need it to be `submit` in order to make `POST` so i am able to load the value of `select` field into my `php` variable, but I dont want to loose the data user put into..

Answer (score 0):

If you add `return false;` to the function called when the form is submitted it will prevent the form from submitting.

```
function createRow(){
    /*Code*/
    return false;
}
```

Comment: but the problem is that the form placed only in first column. Returning false at the end of function has no effect

Answer (score 0):

```
    table.insertAdjacentElement('beforeEnd', row);
    counter++;
    return false;
}
```

The extra `return false;` makes it so the form is not submitted like it normally would be.